# What's wrong with this SQL code syntax?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to implement this code into my script but I get a syntax error

`INSERT INTO prospectstbl ( 'customerNumber', 'namePerson1', 'LnamePerson1', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'homePhone', 'cellPhone', 'clientSince', 'clientLevel', 'closingDate', 'lastPaymentDate', 'currentBalance', 'repurchaseDate', 'repurchaseAmount', 'delinquentBalance', ) VALUES ('20713254', 'Sonia', 'Amaya', '338 Railroad Ave', 'Ctr Moriches', 'NY', '11934', '6318788386', '6318137972', '10/24/2002', '1', '7/26/2011', '8/11/2011', '$792.15', '', '$0.00', '$0.00')`

and the error I get:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''customerNumber', 'namePerson1', 'LnamePerson1', 'street', ' at line 2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the '' at the column names and the `,` at the last column:

```
INSERT INTO prospectstbl ( customerNumber, namePerson1, LnamePerson1, street, city, 
state, zip, homePhone, cellPhone, clientSince, clientLevel, closingDate, 
lastPaymentDate, currentBalance, repurchaseDate, repurchaseAmount, delinquentBalance ) 
VALUES ('20713254', 'Sonia', 'Amaya', '338 Railroad Ave', 'Ctr Moriches', 'NY', '11934', '6318788386', '6318137972', '10/24/2002', '1', '7/26/2011', '8/11/2011', '$792.15', '', '$0.00', '$0.00')
```

Comment: Thanks. the problem was the , at the end.

Answer (score 3):

There is a comma `,` after `'delinquentBalance'`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
`
```

instead of

```
'
```

And remove `,` after , `delinquentBalance`

or you can remove list of your columns

```
INSERT INTO prospectstbl VALUES ('20713254', 'Sonia', 'Amaya', '338 Railroad Ave', 'Ctr Moriches', 'NY', '11934', '6318788386', '6318137972', '10/24/2002', '1', '7/26/2011', '8/11/2011', '$792.15', '', '$0.00', '$0.00')
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, single quotes (`'`) are generally used for quoting literal values (strings and such) and indicating that certain tokens are NOT fieldnames. Graves (`) are used to indicate fields.

Try quoting your column names with graves (`) instead.

Also, as others have said, you have an extra comma at the end of your column name list. Remove this as well.